# DQL return results when query returns 0 results and preventng #REF

Tags: excel-formula, dql, alm

I have a formula that looks up at external data query (HP ALM Business Views).

The formula I'm using is;

```
   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,bvtbl_678a2f62_71fd_4e3e_bc63_7f1a176fae2d,2,FALSE),0)
```

The horrible long table name I cannot change as it won't refresh the table within a tool in Excel. Anyway, when the table returns no results which can happen often the table name is deleted and replaced with #REF!.. I can't really reference a specific cell due to the complexity of the report. And I don't really want users of the report to have to update these themselves every time the data table is blank...

The other option I have is to write the DQL query so that if no results are returned for;

```
Select Defects.severity,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Assigned', 1)) As Assigned,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Awaiting Release', 1)) As "Awaiting Release",
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Being Resolved', 1)) As "Being Resolved",
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Blocked', 1)) As Blocked,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Closed', 1)) As Closed,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Deferred', 1)) As "Deferred",
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Failed Retest', 1)) As "Failed Retest",
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Fixed', 1)) As Fixed,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Investigation', 1)) As Investigation,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'New', 1)) As New,
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Open', 1)) As "Open",
Sum(DECODE(Defects.status, 'Retest', 1)) As Retest
From Defects
Where Defects.user_template_06 = '07 - User Acceptance Testing (UAT)' 
And Defects.project = 'xxx'
Group By Defects.severity
Order By Defects.severity
```

Then return a value... Please note this is DQL which is just a massive pain.